# Не создаётся ScrollBar в QScrollArea, PyQt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt6, qscrollarea, qscrollbar

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данной задачи.
Требуется следующее:

1. По кнопке в главном окне должно открываться второе окно.
2. Во втором окне должна быть `QScrollArea` с содержимым и Скроллбарами (вертикальным и горизонтальным).

Важно, чтобы второе окно не являлось полностью `QScrollArea`, а только содержало её внутри себя.

Прикладываю свой код.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его исправить, чтобы появился скроллбар. Огромное спасибо за ответы!

```
import sys
 
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QScrollArea, QLabel
 
 
class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(500, 500))
        scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        dict_303 = {}
        for i in range(0, 50):
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'] = QLabel(f'Номер {i}', scroll_area)
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].move(0, 0 + 16 * i)
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].show()
        scroll_area.show()
 
 
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = Window_303()
        button = QPushButton("Открыть окно", self)
        button.show()
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_window_303)
        self.show()
 
    def show_window_303(self, checked):
        self.w.show()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except:
        print("Exiting")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите свои импорты и попробуйте.

```
import sys
''' 
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, \
    QWidget, QScrollArea, QLabel
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 
 
class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
# ?      self.setFixedSize(QSize(500, 500))
        self.resize(QSize(500, 500))                                      # +
        
        scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)                                   # 1
        scroll_area.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 230, 170))           # 2
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)                              # 3
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()               # 4
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)              # 5      
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)              # 6      
        
        dict_303 = {}
        for i in range(0, 50):
#            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'] = QLabel(f'Номер {i}', scroll_area)
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'] = QLabel(f'Номер {i}')         # 7

#            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].move(0, 0 + 16 * i)
#            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].show()
#        scroll_area.show()
            layoutV.addWidget(dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'])              # 8

        dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].setText(
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].text() + 
                ' Это последняя строка и она длиннее других.')
 
 
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  
        
        self.w = Window_303()
        
        self.button = QPushButton("Открыть окно", self)
        self.button.show()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_window_303)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
#        self.show()
 
    def show_window_303(self, checked):
        self.w.show()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()
    main_window.resize(200, 500)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Супер, спасибо!
Переделал импорты обратно на PyQt6 и всё работает.
Параллельно нашёл другой код решения, его тоже сейчас приложу отдельным комментарием.

Comment: @Альберт пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи изменил в своём коде следующий блок:

```
class Window_303(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window_303, self).__init__(parent)
 
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll_area.setGeometry(0, 0, 420, 180)
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(False)
 
        container = QWidget()
        scroll_area.setWidget(container)
        dict_303 = {}
        geometry = QRect(10, 10, 0, 0)
        for i in range(0, 50):
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'] = QLabel(f'Номер {i}', container)
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].adjustSize()
            dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].move(geometry.bottomLeft())
            geometry |= dict_303[f'label_number_{i}'].geometry()
 
        geometry.setTopLeft(QPoint(0, 0))
        container.resize(geometry.size())
```